# Use resource font directly in Java

Tags: java

How to use resource font directly in Java?

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to do? At the simplest level you can just create a new Font(...) and draw using it with Graphics.setFont(...) and Graphics.drawString(...)

Comment: @SamSol: Just out of curiosity, what on earth are you working on? I see you've asked dozens of questions about seemingly random and unrelated topics with only a few minutes inbetween.

Answer (score 9):

To load a font (.ttf) from file, have a look at [Load font from ttf file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Loadfontfromttffile.htm).

Key lines being:

```
InputStream is = DemoFonts.class.getResourceAsStream(fName);
font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```

The font could then be used for a `JLabel` through the usual `setFont` method.

Comment: How set font size for this font?

Comment: Using [`Font.deriveFont(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(float))