# Display Emoji character in JTable

Tags: java, swing, encoding, fonts, jtable

I want to display [loudspeaker character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50a/index.htm) in a `JTable`:

```
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
    {
        switch (col) {
            [...]
            case 2:
                String symbol = "\uD83D\uDD0A";
                return "State " + symbol;
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
```

Unfortunaly i just see an square box. I'm not sure if i have to set an specific `Font` supporting this character or to apply an other encoding.

**For Googlers looking for a solution:**
I implemented a CustomRenderer for the JTable like @trashgod sugested. Examples are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/1965084) or [here](http://open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=64).

Comment: If you're not sure of the character encoding, check out [emoji-java](https://github.com./vdurmont/emoji-java) which contains the right unicode value for every emoji.

Comment: I tried emoji-java, but it just helps to ease the use of such characters but it doesn't help to solve the font problem. Finally i suceeded with @trashgod sugestion of implementing the TableCellRenderer to view icons

Comment: I can't display emoij in a JTable cell. it doesn't work. I have a renderer setup and I'm using Vincent's emoij-java. Inside the renderer, I already have setText(EmojiParser.parseToUnicode(value.toString())) where value is the object--it was a StringBuffer, that's why I need toString(). What's missing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need two things:

- A font containing the required glyph, loaded as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934946/230513).
- A `TableCellRenderer` in which to use the font, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164751/230513).

Alternatively, consider a `TableCellRenderer` that implements the `Icon` interface, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/230513). The graphics context's `fill(Polygon)` and `drawArc()` methods should produce a satisfactory result.

Comment: OK, thank you. I solved the problem by using TableCellRenderer to display the icons as you  suggested!